# If $\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)a_k = n(n+1)(4n-1)$, find $a_n$

Tags: summation

I'm not getting any idea what to do with this problem. If given that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (2k-1)a_k = n(n+1)(4n-1)$ then how can we find out $a_n$.

I need some hints to start.

Comment: Consider what happens if $n=1$ and see if that is enough information to ascertain the value of $a_1$.  Now armed with the knowledge of $a_1$ can you use that to do similar and find $a_2$?

Comment: @Anonymous you might consider posting your solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finding a solution**

One way is to look for a solution of the form $a_n=\alpha n + \beta$.

Then $$\begin{split}
n(n+1)(4n-1)&=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)a_k \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)(\alpha k+\beta)\\
&= 2\alpha  \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^2\right)+(2\beta-\alpha)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right) -\beta \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1\right)\\
&=2\alpha\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+(2\beta-\alpha)\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\beta n
\end{split}$$
and by expanding the right-hand side, you can identify the value of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

**This is the only solution**

This finds a solution, but doesn't show this is the only solution. But we can prove it is.

Note that if $a=(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n)^T$ and $b=(6, 42, \dots, n(n+1)(4n-1))^T$, then any solution $a$ verifies $Ma=b$ where
$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0&\dots &0\\
1&3& 0&\dots&0\\
\vdots\\
1&3&5&\dots&n(n+1)(4n-1)
\end{array}\right)$$
This matrix is obviously invertible, so there is only one solution to $Ma=b$.

**Addendum**
Note that the inverse of $M$ can be explicitly computed. Indeed, $M=PD$ where
$$P=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 0&\dots &0\\
1&1& 0&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\\
1&1&1&\dots&1
\end{array}\right)$$ and $D$ is the diagonal matrix $$D=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 \\
&3& \\
&&\ddots\\
&&&n(n+1)(4n-1)
\end{array}\right)$$
$D$ is easy to invert, and
$$P^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 \dots \\
-1&\ddots& \ddots&\\
0&\ddots&\ddots\\
\vdots&\ddots&-1&1\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Setting $n=1$ we get  $a_1 = 6$.

Call $b_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (2k-1)a_k = n(n+1)(4n-1)$.

Then, for $n>1$, on the one hand, we have $b_n - b_{n-1} = (2n-1) a_n$, on the other hand we have $b_n - b_{n-1} = n(n+1)(4n-1) - (n-1)(n)(4(n-1)-1) = (2n-1) 6 n$.

Cancel $2n-1$ to get $a_n = 6n$.